# netbeans don't run jsp & servlet project on mac

Tags: tomcat, servlets, netbeans

when I run servlet project netbeans say wait for starting tomcat but when tomcat start and I can access it from browser tomcat still waiting for it and after 2 min back error

```
ant -f /Users/peter/NetBeansProjects/support -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=/Users/peter/NetBeansProjects/support run
    init:
    deps-module-jar:
    deps-ear-jar:
    deps-jar:
    library-inclusion-in-archive:
    library-inclusion-in-manifest:
    compile:
    compile-jsps:
    Starting Tomcat process...
    Waiting for Tomcat...
    Starting of Tomcat failed.
    /Users/peter/NetBeansProjects/support/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1052: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
    See the server log for details.
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 50 seconds)
```

I use netbeans 8.1 and 8.2, tomcat 8.5.4 and 8.0 and 7

I try a lot of answer in stackoverflow but nothing happened like:

1. adding server="Apache-Coyote/1.1" to connector of server.xml file
2. Netbeans->Preferences->General->Proxy setting to No Proxy
3. uncheck servers->platform->Use IDE Proxy Settings
4. ...

if I develop war file manually to tomcat manager its work fine but it is getting a lot of time from me if i want check only a little change in project

Comment: Just a "me too". How to reproduce it on macOS Sierra, Netbeans 8.2, Tomcat 8.0.27: create a simple Java Web Project, a simple index.jsp page and run it. Tomcat is listening on localhost:8084, but the app never deploys.

Answer (score 1):

What did work for me (after noticing the same problem): open Netbeans preferences, change "Use System proxy Settings" to "No proxy". Had to kill the Tomcat process. After that deployment was OK.

What is funny (if you like fighting the IDE and environment instead of using it for coding) is that I never recall setting that or even being aware of it. Used Netbeans 8.* for years, first time that happened.